# What variables should be matched to keep PHP and JS facebook SDK user data live between sessions?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I have a website in construction (not a localhost), which worked fine when I started from scratch using facebook examples, but now after adding lots of JS and jquery, I haven't been able to make it work anymore.

**The login status is lost intermitently every other load (sometimes it retains the logged-in user one more reload), but it's driving me crazy!**

I've read that using the SDK, the cookies are sent and retrieved automatically, but

I suspect about me having renamed some fb user id, or some difference between php and javascript cookies.

Can you recall some key variables that should match or some process that must be built by hand because is not included in the SDK or tends to fail in certain scenarios?

In Firefox, the problem is worse: The php always fail. So even when the JS works intermittently, when it works the php makes its part to make the user login to fail.

Comment: I made a website once and it didn't work either. Do you know why? On a serious note, you should attempt to isolate your problem, because in this form any answer you get will be a shot in the dark. Start removing stuff that you added between the moment when the site worked and now and when you figure out the exact pieces that make it fail either fix them yourself because it's obvious why or post here to get help otherwise.

Comment: I think it's a valid question. Everywhere there are instructions for php, js, but not for keeping them synchronized. The "it does it automatically" obviously was not that automatically. Some parameters should be respected, and I just need to know that. 
I will post it here once solved. I wanted to start with the basics, before to go into the mission of removing code little by little, because the fb code is so woven with the rest of the functions, that I don't know yet how I'll do it.

Comment: i am certain the question is valid and an answer to it would be most welcome. Unfortunately, without some code to go on, i can't provide that answer and it seems others are reluctant as well. Perhaps instead of removing code, you could create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) from scratch?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the code to protect the idea.

If I knew how to efficiently create an SSCCE from my code faster than it takes me to figure it out myself, I would be experienced enough not to need the answer for this question. 

For this question I count on one of the other reasons that makes people to answer here, other than "not knowing the answer but helping to proofread", which is "someone knows the key or encountered this error before". 

No rush. I'll figure it out eventually, and I rather ask for the next visitors that encouter this problem.